# How to add a list of elements into another list at a certain index without removing or replacing any elements

Tags: scala

Learning Scala right now to prepare for college
I want to add a list into another list at a certain index without replacing elements at that index. For instance, if I have an initial list:

```
var list1: List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to add `List(4,1,5)` into it so that it will become:

```
var list1: List[Int] = List(1,2,4,1,5,3,4)
```

Edit: I've tried creating new lists and adding the head of the first list, the list I want to add to the first, and the tail of the first list to return a brand new list.

This is what I did but I was wondering if there were any more efficient and "smarter" ways. I've done some research on insert but I'm not sure if insert satisfies what I'm trying to do as I don't understand insert fully.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want a _(tail)_ recursive solution? Or using higher order functions, Or are you asking if there  method that already does it for you? - BTW, it is quite a strange requirement.

Comment: I've tried creating new lists and adding the head of the first list, the list I want, and the tail of the first list to make a brand new list. This is what I did but I was wondering if there were any more efficient and "smarter" ways. I've done some research on insert but I'm not sure if insert satisfies what I'm trying to do as I don't understand insert fully.

Comment: Please add the code you wrote to the question as well as all you said in that comment.

Comment: Sorry, not really familiar with StackOverflow, was recommended by my CS teacher to post questions on this for help.

Comment: Sure, no problem and welcome to the community. Take a look to [**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ;)

Comment: Anyways, [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/cNlRUd1NRFiq6ahbOTecMA/4) is a hand made an implementation of a simpler version of `patch`

Answer (score 3):

Scala collections have a `patch` member, which can replace or insert elements:

```
var list1 = List(1,2,3,4)
list1.patch(2, List(4,1,5), 0)
```

Note: inserting elements is done by telling the collection to replace 0 elements.

Answer (score 2):

A key part of learning Scala is learning the standard library, which has a rich set of classes and methods to handle a lot of standard operations. In this case the `splitAt` method on a collection is going to help:

```
var list1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val list2 = List(4, 1, 5)

val (pre, post) = list1.splitAt(2)

pre ++ list2 ++ post
```

This is a "smart" way of doing it because it clearly and simply shows the sequence of operations that is being done, making the code easier to write and easier to maintain.

Note that this is safe in the case where the initial list is shorter than 2 elements because `splitAt` takes care of this and just returns the initial list in `pre` and leaves `post` empty.

Comment: I am still learning, as you can see from the answer from @Suma using the superior `patch` method!

Answer (score -1):

```
  def insertlistAtIndex(index : Int , original : List[Int], appendedList : List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
    original.
      zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (elem, ind) =>
        if(ind == index)
          appendedList :+ elem // append the element at that index
         //  appendedList ::: List(elem) more efficient solution (concatenation)
        else
          List(elem)
      }
  }

  val list1: List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4)
  val list2 : List[Int] = List(4,1,5)
  val expectedResult : List[Int] = List(1,2,4,1,5,3,4)
  val insertAtIndex = 2

  assert(insertlistAtIndex(insertAtIndex,list1,list2) == expectedResult )
```

Here is another solution, it's more flexible and functional, the idea is to zip the list with its index, move through each element in the list, and when you arrive at the index you want to put the other list, you insert that list there, as well as the element that was originally at that element(shown in two ways). This way, you avoid unnecessary exceptions even if the index supplied is out of range. Hope this helps.

Comment: Very inefficient btw.

Comment: More flexible and functional than what?